# Angular: Weird if statement behaviour in app.module.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, build, environment

we recently experienced weird behaviour in our app.module.ts. We were using environment.ts and environemnt.prod.ts file to include/exclude specific library in imports array of the module(library should be excluded for production build). It looked something like this:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'
//
@NgModule({
//
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    environment.production ? [] : libraryXXX,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
```

we found out after days of barren investigation that libraryXXX is included in build every time, even with --prod flag. We tested what's the problem - the value from environment.ts/prod.ts file was read correctly, but for whatever reason comparision always returned false. What I mean by always: replacing above fragment with:

```
environment.production == true ? [] : libraryXXX
```

or

```
environment.production == false ? [] : libraryXXX
```

did not change a thing - library WAS ALWAYS included. Like the if statement was broken(?). Extracting it to variable didn't change a thing. We ended up doing semi-hacky solution like:

environment.ts

```
import { libraryXXX } from 'whatever'

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  libraryXXX: libraryXXX
}
```

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  libraryXXX: []
}
```

and simply referening to environment.libraryXXX in app.module.ts. But out of the curiosity - can anyone explain to me why simple if statement failed? Since it was app.module.ts I could not debug it, or even see console output, to know what's going on. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Conditional statements and expressions are most certainly not broken. Additionally, the behavior you experiencing is to be expected. The compiler can't remove the library because it doesn't know what the value of the production flag is going to be at runtime. This is not how conditional bundling is done and you cannot do it this way

Comment: This should work. The question is, how did you determine that the library is ‘always included’?

Comment: @MikeOne we tried simply running something like:

"true ? [] : libraryXXX"
and
"false ? [] : libraryXXX".

The difference was in output files. This particular library messed up bundle file. We could easily see that bundle without library works fine, and bundle with library is broken. So when leaving any kind of 'if' statement as described above - build was ALWAYS messed up.

Comment: Well, despite that condition, the lib will still have an import. The statement just prevents it from imported in the module scope. Should be tree-shaked out though.. unless that module is a bit dodgy..

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'

const targetModules = [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
];

if (environment.production) {
   targetModules.push(libraryXXX);
}

//
@NgModule({
//
  imports: targetModules,
//
```

Comment: Looks promising, I will definitely give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

You can import both libraries, the prod and the mock version.

Then you can decide (environment.production) which of both your will provide:

```
providers: [
   {
      provide: DbTrassenanfrageStatusService,
      useClass: environment.production ? XyzMockService : XyzService
   }
]
```

If you are talking about modules: 
Give this a try:

```
const exports = [];
if (environment.production === true) {
  exports.push(ModuleXyyyz);
  console.info('FactoryModule: ModuleXyyyz;');
} else {
  console.info('FactoryModule: nothing;');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ModuleXyyyz
  ],
  exports
})
export class FactoryModule {
}
```

Then import FactoryModule in your app module.

To 'choose' the environment.prod.ts config, just build or start it via --prod flag:

```
ng serve --prod
ng build --prod
```

See the [angular cli doc](https://angular.io/cli/build) for more information (--prod , --configuration, ...)

If you have an environment.*.ts like this:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    env: 'prod',
    version: '{BUILD_VERSION}',
    commitHash: '{COMMIT_HASH}',
    showVersionIndicator: false,
    routerTracing: false,
```

...then you can print out a field like version at startup (in your app component):

```
console.info('Version: ', environment.version);
```

Comment: That's not what he's trying to do. He's trying to have the dependency on the development version elided at build time but based on a run time condition

Comment: environment.production   is a build time condition, not a runtime condition.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing the CLI flag `--configuration production` with the environment object? Can you show me where this is documented in Angular's CLI?

Comment: You can set the config with: "ng build  --configuration=XXX ".  Then the environment.XXX.ts  is used (it will be copied over the environment.ts file).   In this ts file you can have production:true/false or whatever.

Comment: Yes of course. What I am saying is that the compiler will not elide the import in the question

Comment: Sorry . I'm not an english nativ speaker. What is the meaning of elide ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214429/discussion-between-marc-and-aluan-haddad).

Comment: I also tried runnning "--configuration production" - this didn't change a thing. I believe I also used some flag like "--target xxx" but I might be confusing something here. Generally speaking the files environment.ts and environment.prod.ts were used correctly. I checked that by refering to field that I created in one file and didnt create in the other - on build process it was spitting out errors when I tried to get non-existing field - everything worked as expected. I also put production:true in both files - the result of comparision was always false....

Comment: --configuration production will only work if you have  the file  environment.production.ts (and some extensions in angular.json).  But you don't have this.    You can use   --c prod    or  --prod. A typical start script is like this:  ng build --deleteOutputPath=true --prod --build-optimizer --serviceWorker=true --aot=true  --base-href /